# MySQL: How to select from table based on info in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have two tables...

**Tickets**

```
id | customer
```

**Customers**

```
id | name
```

I need to **select * from tickets where the customer of that ticket is named John**. I tried using the `JOIN` query below but when using `mysqli_fetch_array()` to get the data, it returns the ticket 'customer' field incorrectly. It's the same as the ticket 'id' field which makes no sense.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tickets 
INNER JOIN customers ON tickets.customer = customer.id 
WHERE customer.name = 'John';
```

How can I accomplish this? I feel like this has to be on Stack Overflow somewhere but I had no luck.

Comment: Hi. (Obviously,) This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `INNER` and write your table name in order (add s to customer) if your Table named customers like this:

```
select * from tickets join customers ON (tickets.customer = customers.id) where customers.name = 'John'
```

Comment: `Join` and `Inner Join` are equivalent.. Why do you think remove `inner` will solve the problem?

Comment: I knew, but in this example he don't need inner, I have updated it.

Comment: All I needed to do was replace * with tickets.* and that provided the correct set of data in a fetch array.

Comment: This code does not work. Replace * with tickets.*

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. This was the correct query...

```
SELECT tickets.* FROM tickets INNER JOIN customers ON tickets.customer = customers.id WHERE customers.name = 'John'
```

I needed the data from the tickets table so replacing `*` with `tickets.*` seemed to provide that.

Comment: This can not be correct, because your table name is plural and your are using `customer.id`

Comment: I just corrected it.